# Using branch cut for Log(z) to compute $Log(z^2-1)$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Why can we use the branch cut for Log(z) - namely, removing the interval (−∞,0] - when computing $Log(z^2)$?

Comment: Compute $\log(z^2)$ or $\log(z^2-1)$.?

Comment: Sorry, $log(z^2-1)$